# How to access controller action from production command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller action that changes the status of all records in the database. I want to run it in production. On local server, I can access rails console and do

```
=> x= WelcomeController.new
=> x.method_name
```

On production I don't have rails console. Can I run controller method directly from command line? What's the preferred way to perform this kind of task? I can move the method anywhere like in helper etc.

Comment: you can run a IRB console in the production mode : `rails console production` will load the `production` env, if defined. By default, `rails console` will run `rails console development` ; But I don't think you should call a Controller method in the console. Why not connect to your website and trigger the controller's action? Or eventually make a rake task of the logic behind the controller's action?

Comment: If you mean connect to website through a browser, it will timeout because the task will take long time.

Comment: then make a Rake task of it OR make a controller action triggering this specific rake task ;-)

Comment: I ended up making a rake task. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

Keeping such logic in controllers is a bad practice. You definitely should move it to a model or service layer. I recommend you to take a look at [this article](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/).

Comment: The article is totally off topic.

Comment: @JamilKhan you are wrong, you should use a Service class to hold the logic of your process. Then either a Controller's action, Rake Task OR directly in your console you could call this service class and ask it to perform the logic. The article is not totally off topic, some suggestions are not for you but the concept of refactoring is very relevant for your case.